# R Language : Convert Categorical to numeric

Tags: r, database, svm, numeric

**Hello every one , i am new to R Language and i am trying convert data from categorical to numeric , i read Database.csv and i made all opeartions but i face Error in results and code not run ,
Error "error-in-r-arguments-imply-differing-number-of-rows-4 7"

Note : My data base consists of one row only and i tried on other database consist of from multi rows and all operations successed .

this is my database and below my Code .
https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZbbjNZoNfJRmssXnSj8tQq6qjOyJayKwyX

any one help me please .
**

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
setwd("C:/Users/maher/Desktop/R")

# Load required libraries
library(vegan)
library(dummies)
library(dummy)
library(e1071)
attr = c('id', 'age', 'exp', 'inc', 'zip', 'family', 
     'ccavg', 'edu', 'mortgage', 'loan', 
     'securities', 'cd', 'online', 'cc')

# Read the data using csv file
data = read.csv(file = "One.csv", 
            header = TRUE, col.names = attr)

# Removing the id, zip and experience. 
drop_Attr = c("id", "zip", "exp")
attr = setdiff(attr, drop_Attr)
data = data[, attr]
rm(drop_Attr)

# Convert attribute to appropriate type  
cat_Attr = c("family", "edu", "securities", 
         "cd", "online", "cc", "loan")
num_Attr = setdiff(attr, cat_Attr)
cat_Data <- data.frame(sapply(data[,cat_Attr], as.factor))
num_Data <- data.frame(sapply(data[,num_Attr], as.numeric))

data = cbind(num_Data, cat_Data)

# Do the summary statistics and check for missing values and outliers.
summary(data)

#------------------------------------------------------

ind_Num_Attr = num_Attr
rm(num_Attr)
ind_Cat_Attr = setdiff(cat_Attr, "loan")
rm(cat_Attr)

# Standardizing the numeric data
cla_Data = decostand(data[,ind_Num_Attr], "range") 
rm(ind_Num_Attr)

# Convert all categorical attributes to numeric 
# 1. Using dummy function, convert education and family        categorical**strong text** attributes into numeric attributes  
edu = dummy(data.frame(data$edu))
family = dummy(data.frame(data$family))
cla_Data = cbind(cla_Data, edu, family)
ind_Cat_Attr = setdiff(ind_Cat_Attr, c("edu", "family"))
rm(edu, family)

# 2. Using as.numeric function, convert remaining categorical attributes into numeric attributes 
cla_Data = cbind(cla_Data, sapply(data[,ind_Cat_Attr], as.numeric))
ind_Attr = names(cla_Data)
cla_Data = cbind(cla_Data, loan=data[,"loan"]) 
str(cla_Data)
cla_Data <- data.frame(sapply(cla_Data,as.numeric))
summary(cla_Data)
write.csv(cla_Data,"OneAfter.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some revised code.

-- Use `sep = ";"` in `read.csv`

-- I have used `colClasses` on `read.csv` to set the initial types correctly. I prefer this to be clear about the correct types. This eliminates some conversions

-- I removed all the `rm` statements because it makes code difficult to read and generally isnt necessary

-- your remaining conversions with sapply look correct.

-- NOTE: I added data[2,] <- data[1,] to add a second row of test data. I believe that some of your sapply did not work correctly because there was only 1 row which was treated as a vector. Remove this for your full file

```
# Load required libraries
library(vegan)
library(dummies)
library(dummy)
library(e1071)
attr = c('id', 'age', 'exp', 'inc', 'zip', 'family', 
         'ccavg', 'edu', 'mortgage', 'loan', 
         'securities', 'cd', 'online', 'cc')
classes = c("NULL", "numeric", "NULL", "numeric", "NULL", "factor",
            "numeric", "factor", "numeric", "factor",
            "factor", "factor", "factor", "factor")

# Read the data using csv file
data  <- read.csv(file = "~/Downloads/one.csv", sep = ";", 
                  col.names = attr, colClasses = classes)
data[2,] <- data[1,]

num_Attr <- names(data)[sapply(data[1,], class)== "numeric"]
cat_Attr <- names(data)[sapply(data[1,], class)== "factor"]

# Do the summary statistics and check for missing values and outliers.
summary(data)

#------------------------------------------------------

ind_Num_Attr = num_Attr
ind_Cat_Attr = setdiff(cat_Attr, "loan")

# Standardizing the numeric data
cla_Data = decostand(data[,ind_Num_Attr], "range") 

# Convert all categorical attributes to numeric 
# 1. Using dummy function, convert education and family        categorical**strong text** attributes into numeric attributes  
edu = dummy(data.frame(data$edu))
family = dummy(data.frame(data$family))
cla_Data = cbind(cla_Data, edu, family)
ind_Cat_Attr = setdiff(ind_Cat_Attr, c("edu", "family"))

# 2. Using as.numeric function, convert remaining categorical attributes into numeric attributes 
cla_Data = cbind(cla_Data, sapply(data[,ind_Cat_Attr], as.numeric))
ind_Attr = names(cla_Data)
cla_Data = cbind(cla_Data, loan=data[,"loan"]) 
str(cla_Data)
cla_Data <- data.frame(sapply(cla_Data,as.numeric))
summary(cla_Data)
write.csv(cla_Data,"OneAfter.csv")
```